# LS-00103: Encountered the symbol "; END;"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create an explain plan to my materialized view script:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW('TASK_V_APPLEBANANA', '
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V_APPLEBANANA
    BUILD IMMEDIATE REFRESH FAST START WITH (sysdate) NEXT (sysdate+1*60/(60*60*24)) WITH rowid AS 
    SELECT A.f, B.f
    FROM Apple a join Banana b
    on a.id = b.fid  
    GROUP BY A.f, B.f
');
```

However SQL developer gives me:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 52:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "; END;" when expecting one of the following:

    ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
    date <a string literal with character set specification>
    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
    <an alternat
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:...
```

I am not sure where the `"; END;"` is implicitly places and how to overcome this error. The materialized view script works fine but the whole execute procedure failed.

Comment: Does your code really have `...BANANA', '` at the end of the first line, or is the opening quote for the create statement actually on a line on its own? You should get ORA-01756 from what you've shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SQL*Plus `execute` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm) all has to be on one line, unless you explicitly add continuation characters. When you do this (assuming you have a single quote on its own line; if you had three on the first line you'd get ORA-01756):

```
EXECUTE DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW('TASK_V_APPLEBANANA',
'
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V_APPLEBANANA
    BUILD IMMEDIATE REFRESH FAST START WITH (sysdate) NEXT (sysdate+1*60/(60*60*24)) WITH rowid AS 
    SELECT A.f, B.f
    FROM Apple a join Banana b
    on a.id = b.fid  
    GROUP BY A.f, B.f
');
```

The first line only is converted into an anonymous block like this:

```
BEGIN DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW('TASK_V_APPLEBANANA',; END;
```

... which explains the error message you see.

You could try to force the whole thing onto one line; or use continuation characters (hypens by default):

```
EXECUTE DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW('TASK_V_APPLEBANANA',-
'-
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V_APPLEBANANA-
    BUILD IMMEDIATE REFRESH FAST START WITH (sysdate) NEXT (sysdate+1*60/(60*60*24)) WITH rowid AS -
    SELECT A.f, B.f-
    FROM Apple a join Banana b-
    on a.id = b.fid  -
    GROUP BY A.f, B.f-
');
```

Or with a simpler example:

```
SQL > exec dbms_output.put_line('-
> hel-
> lo-
> ');
```

which works and gets output:

```
hel lo
```

Note the extra space that's been added; you have enough whitespace anyway for that not to matter for what you're doing but it could be an issue for other split strings.

But it's probably much simpler to just skip the SQL*Plus shorthand and write a full anonymous block:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW('TASK_V_APPLEBANANA',
  '
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V_APPLEBANANA
    BUILD IMMEDIATE REFRESH FAST
    START WITH (sysdate) NEXT (sysdate+1*60/(60*60*24))
    WITH rowid AS 
    SELECT A.f, B.f
    FROM Apple a join Banana b
    on a.id = b.fid  
    GROUP BY A.f, B.f
  ');
END;
/
```

... particularly if you're dropping the bulk of that code in from somewhere else and don't really want to have to manipulate it just to meet `execute`'s restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation !